# Able to change / switch a Office 365 (now Microsoft 365) main account domain to one added within the organization?

Tags: microsoft-office, user-accounts, office365, administrator, domain

I have a 365 account with multiple domains. For simplicity's sake lets just use two, the one I made the account with and another I added to the account that I would like to make the the primary domain. Rebranding / not sure if the previous domain will be kept.

Is it easier to just make a new account  with the second domain and migrate all my others there?

Or is there a way I can essentially "swap" the domain I want to be primary with the current main domain?

I hope this makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Migrating everything over to a new tenant can get complicated very quickly. It will usually involve a third party software to get something like all Microsoft Teams messages, channels, and chats transferred successfully. 

I would recommend having your secondary domain added to your current tenant. Then, if I understand your question completely, it would be as easy as going to `portal.azure.com > Active Directory > Custom Domain Names` then making your new domain the primary. 

When you get multiple tenants involved, in my experience, creates more headaches than what they're worth.

Comment: This is indeed the solution I was looking for and simple enough, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Migrating everything over to a new tenant can get complicated very quickly. It will usually involve a third party software to get something like all Microsoft Teams messages, channels, and chats transferred successfully. I would recommend having your secondary domain added to your current tenant. Then, if I understand your question completely, it would be as easy as going to `portal.azure.com > Active Directory > Custom Domain Names` then making your new domain the primary. When you get multiple tenants involved, in my experience, creates more headaches than what they're worth.

Answer (score 0):

[Dr_Xunil](https://superuser.com/users/1078925/dr-xunil) answered my question in the comments. I didn't realize I could change the primary domain just like that. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for accepting @Dr_Xunil's answer -- Erased my previous comment (and upvoted both the question and the accepted answer).  But do also recommend deleting your answer now.  Thanks!